# Get checkbox checked event in gridview

Tags: events, gridview, checkbox, asp.net, aspxgridview

I have a gridview with one column of checkboxes  and other columns with different custom controls .
What I want is that when a checkbox is checked an event is triggered which toggles the visibility of other elements in the row .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the approach, illustrated in the http://www.devexpress.com/example=E2284 Code Central example as a starting point to accomplish this task.